# Couldn't find type definition VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA and I am studying a project inherited by former developer. I see lines of code like this:

```
Public HubCache As Cache
.....
.....
Set HubCache = New Cache
```

I couldn't find what type `Cache` is. I looked for [standard types](https://www.guru99.com/vba-data-types-variables-constant.html) or [User Defined Types](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/user-defined-types.htm).

So I searched all the project for `Type Cache` and in general `Cache` - couldn't find its definition.

Am I missing some core concept of VBA?

Comment: You are missing a reference. Go in VBE, Tools menu -> References... and see one showing 'missing'...

Comment: If not a missing reference, try looking for a `Public Type` variable named `Cache`. `Ctrl + F`, check 'Current Project' and search.

Comment: It could also be a User Defined Class, or a UserForm.  Does the project compile?